# Changing the hostname on a rented dedicated server

Tags: ubuntu, hostname

I would like to change the hostname on my Ubuntu Server 12.04 box that I rent from a dedicated server company. At the moment if I type `hostname` into SSH I get a response like so:

```
cl-21.servercompany.com
```

is there a way to change this? And if I do, will it cause any problems? I'm unsure if the company is likely to use the hostname to connect to the server from inside the database or its static IP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change to hostname of your server you only need to edit `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`
It shouldn't cause any problems, since it won't change the servers DNS entry.